# SSIS - data viewer not showing Derived column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to be able to see derived column in the dataviewer. Please see image below for details.

I have tried disabling and enabling the data viewer, but that did'nt change anything for me.

[image: Please see this image for the issue I am facing.]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Double click the data flow path that has the viewer enabled. Click on the Data Viewer tab. priceRefSource is probably listed in the Unused Columns list. Click on it, and then move it across to the Displayed Columns list.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you Jeremy.

Comment: You're welcome. Since this worked for you, can you mark it as answered?